# What is the difference between "brush aside" and "brush off"?

Tags: ambiguity, phrasal-verbs, colloquialisms, confusables

- He brushed her ideas / accusations aside
- He brushed her ideas / accusations off
- She brushed him off / aside after breaking up

What's the difference between **brush off** and **brush aside**?

I looked the meanings of these verbs up but they're kind of the same.

> ***Brush off*** - refuse to listen to someone, or refuse to consider something.
>
> ***Brush aside*** - to refuse to listen to someone or their ideas.

Comment: Please tell us where you looked them up and what you found. Amongst other things, it saves us repeating the same search and/or explaining differences that you've already seen but don't understand.

Comment: @TrevodD Oxford, Longman and Macmillan Advanced dictionaries. Brush off - refuse to listen to someone, or refuse to consider something. Brush aside - to refuse to listen to someone or their ideas. I haven't seen any differences so far.

Comment: **Brush aside** is what Napoleon intended to do at Waterloo to the Allies Army, and **brush off** is what he did to the warnings from his Marshals who had faced Wellington in Spain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the extra info.

**Selected definitions:**

> **brush something or someone aside**  to dismiss or pay no attention to it or them • *brushed aside all my objections.* [1](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=brush&title=21st)
> **brush something or someone off**  to ignore or refuse to listen to it or them. See also **brush-off**. [1](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=brush&title=21st)
> **brush-off *noun*** (usually **the brush-off**) *colloq*  an act of ignoring, rebuffing or dismissing someone or something in an abrupt or offhand manner. [2](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?xref=21C05236&query=brush-off&title=21st)
> **give someone the brush-off** *colloq* especially in a romance or friendship: to rebuff or reject them; to finish with them in an offhand or blunt way. [2](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?xref=21C05236&query=brush-off&title=21st)
>
> **brush aside** to disregard; ignore: *Our complaints were simply brushed aside.* [3](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/brush)
> **brush off** to rebuff; send away: *She had never been brushed off so rudely before.* [3](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/brush)
>
> **brush someone/thing aside**   dismiss someone or something curtly and confidently:*he brushed aside attacks on his policies* [4](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/brush?q=brush+aside#brush__25)
> **brush someone/thing off**  dismiss someone or something in an abrupt way: *the judge brushed off his pleas for leniency* [4](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/brush?q=brush+aside#brush__25)

I agree that the distinctions can be vague and relate more to nuances. Please bear in mind that I'm discussing British usage here: where differences relate to nuances, they *can* differ between cultures and regions.

I would suggest the following differences:

1. **brush off** is generally the *stronger* of the two phrases: you'll note that several of the definitions refer to *abruptness*, *rudeness*, *bluntness*.
2. In a similar vein:
   **brush aside** has more implication of *disregarding*, *ignoring*; whereas
   **brush off** implies *rebuffing someone*, actually *sending them away*.
3. Usually - but not always - I would **brush off *someone*** but **brush *something* aside**, e.g.:
   *He brushed **aside** all my objections.*
   *She had never been **brushed off** so rudely.*
4. **brush off** can be a noun: **give someone the brush-off**; whereas
   **brush aside** is not used as a noun.
5. Note that **brush off** is used in the context of terminating a relationship, *to finish with them in an offhand or blunt way*; e.g. *he gave her the brush-off*;
   but having terminated their relationship, if they were to meet again, he might ***brush her aside***, i.e. *just ignore her*.

As you'll see, it's difficult to *define* the differences, but I hope these explanations and examples help somewhat.